# Is it possible to re-use css styles in a media query with a non-media query modifier class?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

For example purposes, suppose I have a contrived concept of a Card:

```
<div class="Card">
  <div class="Card-author">{{author}}</div>
  <div class="Card-body">{{body}}</div>
  <div class="Card-timestamp">{{timestamp}}</div>
</div>
```

It has a bunch of styles and quite a few changes to those under a media query for small screens:

```
.Card {...}
.Card-author {...}
.Card-body {...}
.Card-timestamp {...}

@media (max-width: 981px) {
  .Card-author {...}
  .Card-body {...}
  .Card-timestamp {...}
}
```

Is there I DRY way I could re-use those styles easily if I wanted to display this small version of the card above that screen dimension (eg, if i want to display this version of the card in a sidebar)?

Something like:

```
<div class="Card Card--small">  <!-- NOTICE ADDITIONAL CLASSNAME -->
  <div class="Card-author">{{author}}</div>
  <div class="Card-body">{{body}}</div>
  <div class="Card-timestamp">{{timestamp}}</div>
</div>
```

In the html, I could easily add that "modifier" class to the card component, but how do I accomplish this in css short of duplicating this "small" card styling in two places (media query block and a Card--small block?

```
@media (max-width: 981px) {
  .Card-author {...}
  .Card-body {...}
  .Card-timestamp {...}
}
.Card--small {
  /* Same exact styles as the media query rules above */
  .Card-author {...}
  .Card-body {...}
  .Card-timestamp {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile-first approach will help you to solve this problem. Instead of applying `Card--small` to the sibebar version of a card, use `Card--large` class for a main card and make mobile CSS the new default.

```
/* mobile-first styles */
.Card {...}
.Card-author {...}
.Card-body {...}
.Card-timestamp {...}

@media (min-width: 982px) {
  /* style modifications for large screens */
  .Card--large {
    .Card-author {...}
    .Card-body {...}
    .Card-timestamp {...}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this with sass, I'll assume you're OK using standard SASS mixins.  Here's how to do it:

```
@mixin Card--small {
    .Card-author {...}
    .Card-body {...}
    .Card-timestamp {...}
}

.Card--small {
  @include Card--small;
}
@media (max-width: 981px) {
  @include Card--small;
}
```